# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write json

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

```
import json

print(f"Enter some numbers")
userWD = input("--->")
with open("./Users/" + "test" + ".json", "r") as userID:
    tmp = json.load(userID)
    tmpBalance = tmp['Balance']
with open("./Users/" + "test" + ".json", "w") as f:
    newBalance = int(tmpBalance) - int(userWD)
    json.dump(newBalance, tmpBalance)
```

When i run this code , im getting this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to dump to `tmpBalance` (which is a string):

```
json.dump(newBalance, tmpBalance)
```

You want to dump into the file:

```
json.dump(newBalance, f)
```

After you're done with the calculation, `newBalance` is just a number. If you want to retain the complete data structure `{"Balance": 12345}`, you need to assign the new balance value back `tmp`:

```
tmp['Balance'] = newBalance
```

and then write `tmp` to the file, instead of `newBalance`.

---

I would re-arrange things like so:

```
import json

account_file = "./Users/test.json"

with open(account_file, "r") as f:
    account = json.load(f)

print(f"Your account balance: {account['Balance']}.")
wd_amount = input("How much do you want to withdraw? >")
account['Balance'] -= int(wd_amount)

with open(account_file, "w") as f:
    json.dump(account, f)
```